# Searching Information at PDFs

Tags: python, pdf

I am a beginner user at Python / programming world and I am trying to solve a problem.

I have a kind of keyword list. I want to look for these keywords at some folders which contain a lot of PDFs. PDFs are not character based, they are image based (they contain text as image). In other words, the PDFs are scanned via scanner at first decade of 2000s. So, I can not search a word in the PDF file. I could not use Windows search etc. I can control only with my eyes and this is time consuming & boring.

I researched the question on the internet and found some solutions. According to these solutions, I tried to write a code via Python. It worked but success rate is a bit low.

1. Firstly, my code converts the PDF file to image files (PyMuPDF package).
2. Secondly, my code reads text on these images and creates a text information as string (PIL, pytesseract packages)
3. Finally, the code searches keywords at this text information and returns True if a keyword is found.

Example;

```py
keyword_list = ["a-001", "b-002", "c-003"]   
pdf_list = ["a.pdf", "b.pdf", "c.pdf", ...., "z.pdf"]
```

Code should find a-001 at a.pdf file. Because I controlled via my eyes and a.pdf contains a-001. The code found actually.
Code should find b-002 at b.pdf file too. Because I controlled via my eyes and b.pdf contains b-001. The code could not find.

So my code's success rate is %50. When it finds, it finds true pdf file; I have no problem on that. Found PDF really contains what I am looking for. But sometimes, it could not detect the keyword at the PDF file which I can see clearly.

Do you have any better idea to solve this problem more accurately? I am not chasing %100 success rate, it is impossible. Because, some PDFs contain handwriting. But, most of them contain computer writing and they should be detected. Can I rise the success rate %75?

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is to extract the image with the highest possible resolution, which **might** mean not "converting the PDF to an image" but rather "parsing the PDF and extracting the image stream" (given it was 2000's scanned, it is probably a TIFF stream, at that). This is an example using [PyMuPdf](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/examples/extract-imga.py).

You can perhaps try and further improve the image by adjusting brightness, contrast and using filters such as "despeckling". With poorly scanned images I have had good results with sharpening filters, and there are some filters ("erode" and "washout") that might improve poor typewriting (I remember some "e"'s where the eye of the "e" was almost completely dark, and they got easily mistaken for "c"'s).

Then train Tesseract to improve recognition ratio. I am not sure of how this can be done with the Python interface, though.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I asked the question in case of there may be another solution. Apparently, OCR is the only solution or the best one for the problem.

By the way, I changed code what you said. I increased resolution and the code works better now.